# php range from already given name variable array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, web, foreach

So i have this array in the variable $Myarray

```
{ [0]=> object(stdClass)#3216 (3) 
{ ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["name"]=> string(5) "david"}
{ ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["name"]=> string(5) "linda"}
{ ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["name"]=> string(5) "dony"}
```

so i want to echo only id 12 to 13 using foreach range, and the question is.. How do i do that?

because in php, i only can range specific arrays like :

```
<?php
// array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}

// The step parameter
// array(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
foreach (range(0, 100, 10) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}

// Usage of character sequences
// array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i');
foreach (range('a', 'i') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
// array('c', 'b', 'a');
foreach (range('c', 'a') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
?>
```

thanks

Comment: use php array_slice()

Comment: The best way to achieve this is to use Eloquent instead of Query Builder to get the data and Collections methods like [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-wherein) to iterate over specified part of the collection.

Comment: this only work if i have only 3 data or less, i have hundreds of data arrays i need to range

Answer (score 1):

"$object" has the above data you posted.

```
$data = $object[0];
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
  if($val->id == 12 || $val->id == 13)
    echo $val->name;
}
```

Comment: this only work if i have only 3 data, i have hundreds of data arrays i need to range